# Linux / AD integration with SSSD: how to choose what systems a user can log into?

Tags: linux, active-directory, sssd

We are trying out ActiveDirectory integration on some linux systems with SSSD.

So far so good we joined the linux systems to the domain and we can log into linux systems with AD-defined users. Right now every AD user can log into every Linux system which has been integrated with SSSD.

How can I let user Foo log into LinuxServer01 but prevent him to log into LinuxServer02?
And/or how can I block a user to log into every linux systems and just let him on some specific ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend **against** using the filter based access control filters for most deployments for two reasons:

- they are hard to get right
- the filters are applied on the user entry that is logging in. This might have interesting consequences especially if the filter contains a `memberof` attribute while the user is a member of nested groups - since the user entry only contains memberofs to direct parents, the nested groups would never match.

For very simple use cases, such as allowing a user or a group of users, I would recommend to use the [simple access provider](https://jhrozek.fedorapeople.org/sssd/1.12.2/man/sssd-simple.5.html)

For complex use-cases, SSSD supports AD GPOs starting with the 1.12.x series, search the [sssd-ad man page](https://jhrozek.fedorapeople.org/sssd/1.12.3/man/sssd-ad.5.html) for details.

Comment: It should be noted that **simple access provider** cannot handle **expired/locked** accounts and trusted domains.
Here is [more detailed comparing](https://sssd.io/design-pages/active_directory_access_control.html) from SSSD offcial website.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some more RTFM I [found the details in sssd-ad(5)](https://jhrozek.fedorapeople.org/sssd/1.11.6/man/sssd-ad.5.html) - I must have missed them the first time:

- the default `access_provider` is `permit`, so every user that can authenticate is given permission to login to the system. This is explained in [sssd.conf(5)](https://jhrozek.fedorapeople.org/sssd/1.11.6/man/sssd.conf.5.html).
- to manage specific permissions you must set `access_provider = ad`
- you then use `ad_access_filter` as detailed in [sssd-ad(5)](https://jhrozek.fedorapeople.org/sssd/1.11.6/man/sssd-ad.5.html) to define a filter for users that can login

(but I still don't know if there's any way to specify systems one by one on the AD side for a user to allow login)

Answer (score 1):

In your sssd.conf configuration file, you can modify the access filter to meet your needs:

Under the `domain/default` section, try the following:

```
access_provider = ldap
ldap_access_filter = memberOf=cn=GroupName,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com
```

Comment: Some people prefer the LDAP syntax.

Comment: Please note that if you combine id_provider=ad and access_provider=ldap then you must also configure stuff like ldap_uri or ldap connection authentication, the configuration will note be inherited from the AD PROVIDER